# Avoid portal (060) id using

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

Is it possible to SOQL portal ID by Name (or any other field) to avoid id hardcoding

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: have no clear idea which sObject we need to soql

Comment: Is `Site` what you are looking for? `SELECT Id FROM Site`

Comment: Nope, site's id starts with 0DM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to query for [`Portal`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_portal.htm). Objects that are queryable (and don't require the Tooling API) will be [listed in the SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) and support `query()` as an option.

That being said, all Portals have a [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_site.htm) which can be queried a number of different ways.